# Spread operator error in return value, parse error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spread, ecmascript-2018

When trying to directly return an item that contains the spread operator I get a parse error. If I assign it to an object before returning it there is no parse error. I'd like to know why.

When I saw the parse error point to the spread operator my first suspicion was not having ES2018 but through some experimentation I found the spread operator is working.

First WorkoutSets are defined as such.
    `workoutSets: [ { id: 0, group: 0, repeat: 0, dist: 25, rest: 20, speed: "Easy", total: 0, notes: "" } ]`

This shows a parsing error point at ...
    `this.state.workoutSets.map( item =>  { ...item, repeat: e.target.value } )})`

This succeeds:
    this.state.workoutSets.map( item =>  item = { ...item, repeat: e.target.value } )})

This also succeeds: 
    `this.state.workoutSets.map( item =>  item.group === 0 ?  { ...item, repeat: e.target.value} : item)})`

I'm just curious why the first example fails.

Comment: If you intend to do object spreading, and return the object, you need to add braces, `() => ({})`, to differentiate from `() => { return 0; }` a code block. See also [Arrow functions - returning object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Returning_object_literals)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that in your first try you open brackets `{}` so javascript thought it was a code block and in code block `.` was parsed as either 'decimal' or 'object instance property accessor'.

So if you want to do the code with the first style you would do something like

```
set.map(item => {return{...item, foo: 'bar'}})
```

And yes, you will need two pair of brackets with `return`

In the other 2 tries you started with assignment so js understood that you was returning the value.

Answer (score 0):

the `map` function need to return a value for each element is the `WorkoutSets` array,
the first example fails because you just did an assignement and you don't return anything.
on the other hand, the second and third examples succeded because you returned `item`

Answer (score 0):

You have a parsing error because javascript perceives the brakets `{}` after an arrow `=>` as a body of the function. Not as a returning object.

```
item =>  { ...item, repeat: e.target.value }
```

You can think about this part of code as

```
function (item) {
  ...item
  repeat: e.target.value
}
```

This code is not correct.

So if you need to return an object in an arrow function, you need to wrap it in a parentheses `()`:

```
item => ({ ...item, repeat: e.target.value })
```

Comment: Thanks, sure enough it appears to be the parser error. I can actually do this and it will succeed:  `this.state.workoutSets.map( item => { return {...item, repeat: e.target.value}})})` Although the this code is just an experiment. For me the implementation is my third example, where I check if I have the correct item before altering it. Again thanks.